# Match only one word for each starting letter

Tags: javascript, regex

You can see how I want the words to be filtered here:

```js
string = 'Take all first words for each letter... this is a test';
first_letters = {};

words = string.match(/\w+/g);
words.forEach(function(x){
    var first = x[0].toLowerCase();
    first_letters[first] = (first_letters[first] || x);
});

result = [];
for (var x in first_letters) {
    result.push(first_letters[x]);
}

O.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<pre id=O>
```

I'm trying to get the array `result` shown above with only regex, I started trying to get at first the initial letters:

```
result = words.match(/\b(?!\1)(\w)/gi);
```

But `(?!\1)` is not filtering the letters as I thought it would do. You can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/vO4aQ0/1).

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Hello ! You want an array like that = [T,a,f,w,f,e,t,i,a,t] ?

Comment: Maybe use \b\w to get all first letters, then use **JavaScript** to do the rest?

Comment: @I'm_ADR. Nope, in your array `a,f,t` have duplicates, I do not want duplicates.

Comment: @Laurel. Actually, my code works, but I'm trying to get the same result using only regex, which I'm in trouble ;)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Why? You do realize that regexes are not omnipotent?

Comment: @Laurel. Aren't them?

Comment: Is it necessary to follow capture first? can the answer be `(words, for, each, letter, is, test)`? i.e.. you will have one word for each starting letter.. but the last word

Comment: @karthikmanchala. Yes, it should be the first ones

Comment: That would require variable length backtracking.. its  not possible with single regex and javascript.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Certain regex flavors are turing-complete, IIRC. They're Turing-tarpits for most problems, however. PPCG is the site to go to if you want an esoteric solution.

Comment: @Laurel. Yeah, maybe just Retina could do this ;)

Comment: @Laurel. Yeah, [Retina](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77273/48943) did it.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp will find unique first letters only:

```
r = /\b(\w)(?!.*\b\1)/gi;
```

This regexp says:

> Find the first letter after a word break, but only if that same letter does not occur immediately after a word break later in the string (negative lookahead).

```
string = 'Take all first words for each letter... this is a test';

> string.match(r)
< ["w", "f", "e", "l", "i", "a", "t"]
```

To find one word per unique first letter:

```
r = /\b((\w)\w*)(?!.*\b\2)/gi

> string.match(r)
< ["words", "for", "each", "letter", "is", "a", "test"]
```

As @karthik manchala mentioned in a comment, due to the limitations of regexp, this will only find the **last** word starting with each letter. To find the **first** word starting with each letter, you'd have to reverse the words in the string:

```
> string . split(' ') . reverse() . join(' ') . match(r) . reverse()
< ["Take", "all", "first", "words", "each", "letter", "is"]
```

Your initial regexp

```
/\b(?!\1)(\w)/gi
```

was not functioning properly since the `\1` must refer to an earlier capturing group.

Comment: I've also opened a challenge [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77263/48943) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did that !

```
var string = 'Take all first words for each letter... this is a test';

Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] == obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function removeSpecials(string) {
  return string.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g,'');
}

function toLowerCase(string) {
  return string.toLowerCase();
}

function getWords(string) {
  return string.split(' ');  
}

function getChar(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(chars, item) {
    if (!chars.contains(item[0])) { chars.push(item[0]) }
     return chars
  }, []);
}

console.log(getChar(getWords(toLowerCase(removeSpecials(string)))))
```

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNOypw?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```js
var string = 'Take all first words for each letter... this is a test';

// reverse the input string
string = string.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
var re = /\b((\w)[a-z]*)(?!.*?\b\2)/gi;

var words = [], m;
while (m = re.exec(string)) {
    words.push(m[0])
}

document.write(words.reverse().join(","));
```